# Partial Font color in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Wanted to see if there's a way to automate changing the color of the font in cell for selective parts.
For instance, I have in one cell:

`If you have any questions, please <a href="{linker('helpcenter')} style"color: #1a73e8; text-decoration: none;" visit our Help&nbspCenter a>`.

I wanted to the text to be black font, but the code in red. Is this currently possible?

Right now I'm going into each cell and highlighting the specific code and changing color, which is extremely manual.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 12 times.